# 2.8 msi install error 2753

Tags: versions

Tried to install 2.8 from .msi but I am getting an error 2753.
[image]

Comment: You can try the fix described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19251176/error-code-2753-during-install Otherwise just download the archive version (.zip), you don't have to install Blender it runs out of the box.

Comment: nope that didn't work. and can't see a zip download for the new 2.8 finished version on the website

Comment: found zip file and using that however would prefer it to be installed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be about an issue caused by the system/environment, not Blender.

Comment: Fair enough i now have 2.81 and it installed perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to fix the error with the approach described in this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19251177/11562467).

Otherwise you don't need to install Blender, you can also use the archive version. Download the appropriate version for your OS and extract the archive.

- [Blender 2.8 64 bit](https://www.blender.org/download/Blender2.80/blender-2.80-windows64.zip/)
- [Blender 2.8 32 bit](https://www.blender.org/download/Blender2.80/blender-2.80-windows32.zip/)

Alternatively you can also install Blender through [Steam](https://store.steampowered.com/app/365670/Blender/?l=english).